# How do I reinstall OSX with panic error (can't boot into OSX, keeps giving kernel / panic error)

Tags: macos, reinstall, kernel-panic

I can't boot into OSX. I've tried everything to fix the panic / kernel error, but no luck.  Don't think it is a hardware issue because this happened after I did a software update.

How do I do a clean install of OSX?  Do I need my original Macbook Air install disks (can't find them), or can I use my Mac Mini install disks?

Answer (score 2):

You need either your original disks, or a retail disk (when you buy Mac OS X without a computer, e.g. the [Snow Leopard "upgrade" disk](https://superuser.com/questions/63887/clean-installation-of-mac-os-x-10-6-using-upgrade-dvd)). Most likely, the Mac mini bundled OS X disks [will not work](https://superuser.com/questions/205302/can-one-mac-os-x-dvd-be-used-on-multiple-macbooks).

Put a disk in, and hold down `c` while booting to select to boot from DVD drive. Follow the instructions to install Mac OS X. You can select to install while keeping your applications and personal preferences during the setup program.

---

You can try to boot into safe mode by pressing down *shift* during the boot process to see if it works then -- maybe it's just a device driver gone bad.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem about 10 days ago.  I tried everything I could think of.

I ultimately created a USB disk with an image of the DiskWarrior boot disk and it worked very well.  To do this, format an external USB disk with GUID partitions.  Create at least one partition.  Then, 'restore' the partition with an image of the DiskWarrior boot disk.  (mine is v4.3).  You may need to use the Disk Utility option: "Images > Scan Image for Restore..." first.

Now, my system wouldn't boot with a USB disk (possibly yours will, not sure, but if not read on...)

Read this hint from MacOSXHints.com: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060301112336384.

Be sure to read the first couple of comments which show how to do this hint super fast and easy.  In my case, I booted my sick Mac into OpenFirmware using CMD-OPT-O-F, then at the prompt, I simply typed: `boot ud:3,\\:tbxi` where '3' is my special partition.  Booted right up into DiskWarrior!

DiskWarrior was able to rebuild the directory of the Mac.  (It took awhile, but I'm glad I waited it out.)  When I restarted, it booted normally and has been perfect since.

Of course, once you've booted up normally, you can use a retail CD to reinstall in the normal manner for the MacBook Air.

Good luck!